# Unable to connect to a ssh server

Tags: ssh, vpn, openssh

Sir can't connect to assh server through my ssh user id or password.

All the login procedure is done but at the end, the error message say's

"Could not chdir to home directory /home/me-vpnjantit.com: No such file or directory
Connection to ssh-cz1.vpnjantit.com closed."

Comment: sounds like the remote SSH server isn't set up for SSH for your user id and password.  contact the owners of the server.

Comment: But every ssh site says the same thing

Comment: What is *every ssh site*?

Comment: `/home/me-vpnjantit.com` is probably incorrect, and needs to be fixed by the server admin.

Comment: Edit your question and show us the command and results of adding `-v` to your `ssh` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vpnjantit.com features free ssh tunnel, *thanks for the resource information*
NO SHELL is available

You cannot log in to a shell, you can only create a tunnel
More info: https://www.ssh.com/ssh/tunneling

[image]

Comment: Thx for the answer.